# libreoffice calc not responding

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice

Libre Office Calc, 7.3.6.2, is not responding properly. In Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS it keeps asking me to wait while telling me Libre Office is not responding.
All updates have been done. Besides waiting there is nothing to be done.
Is there a bug?
Ton

Comment: Did you try to [reset your user profile](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile)?

Comment: I just did this and the same problem.